# this function executes just once when I click the button for second time it keeps the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

this function executes just once when I click the button for second time it keeps the same value of the first time, even if I change the value in textarea it keeps it the same one.
how can I make executes each Time I click the button???

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function readfile() {
     jQuery.get('file1.txt',function(txt){
    $('#textarea').text(txt)
     });
}
    </script>
  <body>
    <input type="button" name="read" value="read" onclick="readfile()">
    <div>
      <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to be different? It is reading the same static resource file each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`val()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0ye7V9IrVAhUBq48KHcAvDUYQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fval%2F&usg=AFQjCNH-GtfNf_4YLXDtVLm7PPh0POeseA) instead of `text()`

```
 function readfile() {
  jQuery.get('file1.txt', function(txt) {
    $('#textarea').val('').val(txt)
  });
}
```

Comment: `.text()` is jquery function and it will work to set text content